# Lambda expression that will match two collections

Tags: c#, linq

I am using entity framework and I need an example of a lambda expression that will return true if an item in collection1 is in collection2.

For example I want to find out if a student and teacher are in the same class. Each would have a collection of classes associated to them.

This is C# entity framework 5.

What is the mathematical term for this type of relationship for my own future reference or searching. (union, intersection, etc.).

Comment: Coderequests are offtopic here, please share your own attempts first.

Comment: The mathematical term in set theory is an intersection (elements common to both sets), contrasted with union (elements present in either set) and set difference (elements present in one set but not the other set).  Linq provides methods for each (`Intersect`, `Union`, and `Subtract` respectively).

Comment: @drf There is no LINQ `Subtract`; it is called `Except`.

Comment: Actually I am asking for the function call or equivalent.  I really can not add any code to try because it is a single line. Marcin answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is called `Intersect`. You can chain it with `Any()` to check if there is at least one element which belongs to both collections:

```
collection1.Intersect(collection2).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Given something like this:

```
class Class
{
}

class Teacher
{
  public Class[] Classes { get ; }
}

class Student
{
  public Class[] Classes { get ; }
}

class ClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<Class>
{
  public bool Equals( Class x , Class y )
  {
    // your implementation here
  }
  public int GetHashCode( Class obj )
  {
    // your implementation here
  }
}
```

Then code like this would suffice:

```
Teacher teacher = ... ;
Student student = ... ;
ClassComparer classComparer = new ClassComparer() ;

bool shareAClass = teacher
                   .Classes
                   .Any( c => student.Classes.Contains(c,classComparer) )
                   ;
```

Though you should bear in mind the semantics of your collections. If they are arrays (as they are in this example), figuring out if a teacher and a student share a class is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) operation. You might want to rethink the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `Intersect` method however, it sounds like the problem you're having is in defining equality. Equality is arbitrary and when you do `c1.Interstect(c2).ToList()` you're comparing with "reference equality" meaning it's returning a collection with references to the objects referenced by both collections.

What you probably want to do is implement `IEqualityComparer` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx wg

There is an overload of intersect which will also take your equality comparer as an argument and then you can produce the intersection on values you care about. For example, you could have `Person` object with string `first` and `last` properties and deem the objects equal if `lhs.first + lhs.last == rhs.first + rhs.last` where lhs and rhs are instances of type `Person`. If you want to have any custom definition of equality like this (which your question leads me to believe you do) then you'll need to implement an `IEqualityComparer` to use with methods like `Intersect`.

Comment: Custom equality comparers only really apply to linq to objects, not EF.

Comment: @Servy good point, I should have read the question more closely. I guess he should just use a simple `Join` in that case but the question is too much trouble to bother editing with some workable code.